# Performance: System.Diagnostics.Process vs System.Management.Automation.PowerShell

Tags: c#, node.js, performance, powershell

In [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2013/10/31/paap-windows-powershell-as-a-platform-part-2.aspx) by PowerShell Team, they focused on posh commands.

1. Is there a way to call `Create()` without loading any PS command, to make it act like a *system* process executor (substitute of `System.Diagnostics.Process`)? How would we go about executing the following with `System.Management.Automation.PowerShell`:

   ```
   node.exe some_module input_file_path --switch1 --switch2=value2
   ```
2. If 1 is possible, next question; would this perform faster than `Diagnostics.Process.Start()`?
3. Is there a way to keep the instance of PS invoked in an interactive mode (in a background thread), running node.exe in an interactive mode listening to the calls from `IRemoteSource`? As opposed to; *invoke*, *execute command* and *close* for each call.
4. Would this, the interactive mode way, boost performance (given `IRemoteSource` is calling too frequently with large chunks of `node.js` commands)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible and simple:

```
ps.AddScript("node.exe some_module input_file_path --switch1 --switch2=value2");
```

Regarding #2, I doubt it would be faster as there is more machinery to spin up to support the PowerShell engine/workspace.  Regarding #3 & #4 you need to explain a bit more about what you need here. What is an IRemoteSource and how does that interact with node.exe?  FWIW you can execute the PowerShell engine on another thread and the ps.Invoke() call will not return as long as node.exe is running.  If you need interaction between the host app and node.exe you can look at implementing the [PowerShell host interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee706545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. In #3 and #4 the `IRemoteSource` is DI/IoC hook to several web-services and some custom server (network) applications listening on non-reserved ports. The applications would be passing JSON to this PS process. Once the PS is up & ready with node running in interactive mode, would it help performance? In this scenario, choosing PS over `Diagnostics.Process` makes sense?

Comment: If the start up cost of the PowerShell engine is not an issue then the runtime difference in performance between PS and Diagnostics.Process should be minimal.